# Calculate a field in a parent table when a child record is created or modified using QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, relation

In QGIS, I have a feature class named "Water_Crossing" that has a field named "Modified".
I have a relation set up from "Water_Crossing" to 3 child tables "Installation", "Repair" and "Inspection".
When a new record is created or an existing record is modified in one of the child tables I would like to set "Modified" in the parent "Water_Crossing" feature class equal to 1 for the related parent record.
How would I accomplish this?

EDIT:
As per Eurojams suggestion, I have tried the following python script, and it sets the Modified field in the parent table to 1 like I want it to, and then it crashes QGIS with the following error:

Windows fatal exception: access violation

Current thread 0x0009a308 (most recent call first):

Stack Trace

QUndoStack::endMacro :

QgsVectorLayer::endEditCommand :

QgsAttributeForm::saveEdits :

QgsAttributeForm::saveWithDetails :

QgsDualView::featureFormAttributeChanged :

```
def set_water_crossing_modified(child_layer,feature_id, column_index):

    # In an attribute form, this procedure is triggered for 
    # every column in the child table whether it was changed or not
    # and we only need to execute it once.
    # So, since the "Modified" column in the child table has been defaulted to 1 
    # on create or update, whenever this value changes, also
    # change the parent "Modified" column
    # ignore changes to other columns
    
    modified_column_index = child_layer.fields().indexFromName("Modified")
    if column_index != modified_column_index:
        return
        
    # get the global_id of the parent table from the modified child record

    child_modified_feature = child_layer.getFeature(feature_id)
    child_modified_attributes = child_modified_feature.attributes()
    child_column_index = child_layer.fields().indexFromName("Feature_Global_ID")
    feature_global_id = child_modified_attributes[child_column_index]
    print (feature_global_id)

# Get the related parent feature if the "Modified" column in the parent layer is 0

    parent_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Water_Crossing")[0]
    parent_layer.selectByExpression("\"Modified\" = 0 and \"Feature_Global_ID\" = '" + feature_global_id + "'")
    parent_features = parent_layer.selectedFeatures()
    print ("Features to update: ",len(parent_features))
    if len(parent_features) > 0:
        
        # Set the modified column to 1 in the parent feature

        with edit(parent_layer):
            parent_feature = parent_features[0]
            parent_feature.setAttribute(parent_feature.fieldNameIndex('Modified'),'1')
            parent_layer.updateFeature(parent_feature)
            parent_layer.commitChanges()

def data_water_crossing_repair_attribute_changed(child_feature_index, child_column_index, child_changed_value):
child_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Data_Water_Crossing_Repair")[0]
set_water_crossing_modified(child_layer,child_feature_index,child_column_index)

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Data_Water_Crossing_Repair")[0]
layer.attributeValueChanged.connect(data_water_crossing_repair_attribute_changed)
```

Comment: Did you consider to use Python for that? There you can use signals emitted from the child layer and do something with your parent layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a virtual field in the parent table with the following expression:

aggregate(
layer:='Data_Water_Crossing_Repair',
aggregate:='count',
expression:="Modified",
filter:=("Modified" = 1 and "Feature_Global_ID"=attribute(@parent, 'Feature_Global_ID'))) +

aggregate(
layer:='Data_Water_Crossing_Inspection',
aggregate:='count',
expression:="Modified",
filter:=("Modified" = 1 and "Feature_Global_ID"=attribute(@parent, 'Feature_Global_ID'))) +

aggregate(
layer:='Data_Water_Crossing_Installation_Removal',
aggregate:='count',
expression:="Modified",
filter:=("Modified" = 1 and "Feature_Global_ID"=attribute(@parent, 'Feature_Global_ID'))) +

"Modified"